# Azure Repo submodule CI/CD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, azure-repos

In my Azure repo for my function app, I included a submodule that is cloned from another Azure Repos. I try to enable CI/CD pipeline of this function, however, if I change and commit a new change to the submodule's original Azure repo, it cannot trigger a new build and deploy of the function APP. Is there a way to enable CI/CD for Azure repo submodule change?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, you need to enable the `Checkout Submodules` option in the advanced section of the `Get Sources` step.

[image]

You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops#checkout-submodules) for details.